# Silverlight Effect tile shader has artefacts

Tags: silverlight, hlsl, pixel-shader

I'm trying to use this shader:

```
float VerticalTileCount : register(C1);
float HorizontalTileCount : register(C2);
sampler2D Texture1Sampler : register(S0);
float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
    float2 newUv = float2((uv.x * HorizontalTileCount % 1) , (uv.y * VerticalTileCount % 1)) ;
    return tex2D( Texture1Sampler, newUv );
}
```

But it has some artifacts

[image: Lines between tiles]

Comment: where you put this code ?

Comment: silverlight effect, but this picture generated in Shazzam Shader Editor

Comment: where you put this code in code behind or viewmodel side ?

Comment: This code compiled by Shazzam and use in Effect TileEffect : ShaderEffect load in pixel shader: new PixelShader { UriSource = new Uri("/Client.Infrastructure;component/Effects/tile.ps", UriKind.Relative) };

Comment: I'm not very familiar with silverlight, but maybe it's a lod issue, because the `% 1` induce a crack in the texture coordinates. Maybe try a kind of wrapping for the coordinates or `tex2Dlod` to set a fix lod-value.

Comment: Can you provide me sample please? thanks!

Comment: Try to replace `return tex2D( Texture1Sampler, newUv );` with `return tex2Dlod( Texture1Sampler, float4(newUv,0,0) );`. This sets the used lod-level to zero (z is ignored, w contains the level). I hope that works :)